# working with dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have this dictionary

```
goodDay= {'Class':[1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1], 'grade':[1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]}
```

I want to traverse the values of first key and also of second and put this condition to check:

If value of K2 is `1` how many times is K1 is `1` and K1 is `0` 
and if K2 is `0` how many times is K1 is `0` and K1 is `1`.

Comment: Dictionary keys in python do not have an order so the concept of "first" or "second" key is really meaningless.

Comment: Your description is hard to decipher, maybe write what you are trying to do in more general terms?

Comment: The right words can make a lot of difference, as far as i know a dict has this form {key1:value1, key2:value2, ...}

Comment: @recursive: if the OP dict has only 2 key:value pairs, your comment is meaningless to the answer of this question.

Comment: @Lord British: Maybe you are right, but I can't make sense of the rest of the question.  I was hoping if that ordering thing was cleared up the rest might make some sense, but right now, I can't tell if it actually matters.

Comment: @recursive: Yeah but i figure he can code around it without add too much complexity (one if). Can a dict change between iterations or views?

Comment: @Lord British: No guarantees are made by the python spec.

Answer (score 0):

```
c = [[0,0],[0,0]]
for first, second in zip(goodDay['class'], goodDay['grade']):
  c[second][first] += 1
```

You compare the two lists in the dictionary pairwise, since each of the lists has only two values (0 and 1), this means that together(cartesian product) we can have 4 different options (00, 01, 10, 11). So we use 2*2 list to store these. And then iterate through both lists and remember the count into the list. So at the end of execution of above lines, we can read the results from list c as follows:

```
c[0][0] is the number of zeros in goodDay['class'] where at the same location in goodDay['grade'] is zero
c[0][1] is the number of zeros in goodDay['class'] where at the same location in goodDay['grade'] is one
c[1][0] is the number of ones in goodDay['class'] where at the same location in goodDay['grade'] is zero
c[1][1] is the number of ones in goodDay['class'] where at the same location in goodDay['grade'] is one
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain the second half a bit more. (I don't understand that part of the question, either.)

Comment: The Dictionary is as given below:

Comment: goodDay= {'Class':[1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1], 'grade':[1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]} I want to code this way that i should get the count of "1" and also "0" in Class when my grade has value "1" and also vice versa i.e. when my grade has value "0"

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
good_day= {'class':[1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1], 'grade':[1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]}
grade_class = [[0,0],
               [0,0]]

for grade, class_ in zip(good_day['grade'], good_day['class']):
    grade_class[grade][class_] += 1

for class_ in (0,1):
    for grade in (0,1):
        print 'You had', grade_class[grade][class_], 'grade', \
              grade, 'when your class was', class_
```

Output:

```
You had 4 grade 0 when your class was 0
You had 1 grade 1 when your class was 0
You had 1 grade 0 when your class was 1
You had 4 grade 1 when your class was 1
```